# Create operation wcf with parameters matching database fields

Tags: php, wcf, parameters, insert, crud

I want to consume a WCF service in a PHP script and the goal is to insert a record into a database.

My database table has 4 fields..is it possible to create a WCF service that will accept 4 parameters, one for each field?

I guess this is similar to an asks web service with input parameters.

Or is there a better, more efficient way of achieving my goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a WCF Web Service with a simple method that will accept four parameters.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
  [OperationContract]
  void InsertFields(string field1 string field2, string field3, string field4);
}
```

But there are much better ways to do this, for example WCF Data Services and OData.

As you want to consume your service from PHP, I think OData could be a good choice.

Hope this helps.